# Rename [codename-steam] to [code-name-steam]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Can the tag for *Code Name: S.T.E.A.M.* be renamed from [codename-steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codename-steam) to [code-name-steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-name-steam)? I tried to retag [the one question for this game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223477/what-do-amiibo-do-in-codename-s-t-e-a-m), but got an error that the new tag would be too similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Done**. Please allow some time for caching to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

I support this request.

---

[The game](https://codenamesteam.fandom.com/wiki/Code_Name:_S.T.E.A.M._Wiki#:%7E:text=Code%20Name%3A%20S.T.E.A.M.%20is%20a%20turn-based%20action%20strategy,head%20against%20opponents%20in%20local%20and%20online%20battlemodes.) is actually titled:

> Code Name: S.T.E.A.M.

Additionally, in the English language, "codename" isn't traditionally a single compound word like this; it's just generally accepted that way. Official descriptions of a code name keep the words separated instead of compounding them:

> A code name, call sign or cryptonym is a code word or name used, sometimes clandestinely, to refer to another name, word, project, or person.